# How can I create a list view for Opportunity object witch show only records created by users with specific roles?

Tags: opportunity, user, list-view

How can I create a list view for Opportunity object that show only records created by users with specific roles? In particular, I need to create this list that show only records created  by users who have as role a role that contains a specific word in its name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a long route, but you could have a flow set a flag on the record whenever a user with the specific role(s) creates the record. Then filter a list view based on the flag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom formula field on the Opportunity

```
Checkbox 
Is_Created_By_Notable_Role__c (use a name appropriate to your app)

OR(
  CONTAINS('Foo',CreatedBy.UserRole.Name),
  CONTAINS('Bar',CreatedBy.UserRole.Name)
)
```

then have the list filter include `Is_Created_By_Notable_Role__c = true`